# jQuery autocomplete with an integer array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm creating an integer array like that

```
    my_array = new array(60);
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<10;j++){
            my_array[(i*10)+j] = (i.toString())+"."+(j.toString());
        }
    }
```

this should result in an array with

```
my_array[0] = 0.0
```

...

```
my_array[59] = 5.9
```

Now I want to use that list for an autocomplete

```
$( "#my_id" ).autocomplete({
   source: my_array
});
```

It does not work, though. Any ideas why?

Comment: what's the error in colsole btw?

Comment: you should write `my_array = [];` instead of `my_array = new array(60);`

Comment: @Rorschach: I'm getting  `array is not defined` error... I'm such a fool. Just noticed that it should be `new Array(100)` instead of `new array(100)`. Thus writing Array with the big A.

Answer (score 1):

You should write `my_array = [];` instead of `my_array = new array(60);`

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/274/).

Comment: thanks, this works aswell, but see my comment above, just had a spelling error...

Answer (score 1):

this is working code tested on [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbfb4/):

```
var my_array = [];
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<10;j++){
            my_array[(i*10)+j] = (i.toString())+"."+(j.toString());
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){

 $( "#my_id" ).autocomplete({
   source: my_array
});

});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbfb4/)

Comment: thanks, this works aswell, but see my comment above, just had a spelling error...